# The import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport cannot be resolved

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

Hi i am trying to develope a sample project in Spring with REST. i am using Spring 4.0.0.release. to implement hibernate operations i import the      `import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport` but the error shows `The import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport cannot be resolved`. my pom.xml includes :

```
<!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- HIbernate  -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

the link [http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.0.0.M3/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/HibernateDaoSupport.html][1] says that the Spring contains the class : `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport`

Please help me to overcome this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You try to use a hibernate3 support class with hibernate5 that obviously won't work, nor does Spring 4.0 support hibernate 5 you would need Spring 4.2 for that.

Comment: @M.Deinum : So, can you tell me that which version of hibernate i have to include?

Comment: If you want hibernate 3 one of the 3.x ranges obviously.

Comment: i include <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
   <version>3.6.4.Final</version>
  </dependency>                   but still the problem occurs

Comment: What version is `org.springframework-version` pointing to?

Comment: i am using <org.springframework-version>4.0.0.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>

Comment: Does it compile on the command line? Or does it only fail in your IDE?

Comment: i am compiling in IDE "Eclipse Kepler"

Comment: try the command line see if it builds. Wouldn't be the first time maven and eclipse don't play nice. Have you enabled maven integration in eclipse?

Comment: Instead of using an oooold version of Hibernate, you should use the latest version of Spring, which supports Hibernate 5. Or at least use Hibernate 4, and use the classes from the `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4` package.

Answer (score 5):

According to the Maven Repository at http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm/4.0.0.RELEASE

You should be using the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.2.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

If that does not work, try `3.6.9.Final` for hibernate version.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure to integrate Maven in Eclipse.
   In Windows -> preferences -> Maven -> User Settings, provide the settings.xml and see whether the local repository is the same as that of the local repository where the downloads of these jars are occurring.
2. Please use spring framework version 4.2.1.RELEASE and hibernate version 5.0.1.Final

This should probably help. Else, try restarting the eclipse, or do a manual install.

Please let know if it works.

Comment: i changed spring version 4.2.1 and hibernate to 5.0.1, but now it show s some other errors     :    **1)** The import org.springframework.stereotype cannot be resolved    ,    **2)**   The type org.springframework.core.io.InputStreamSource cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files  ,    **3)**      The type org.springframework.core.NestedRuntimeException cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files ,

Comment: **4)**     No exception of type DataAccessException can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable  ,    **5)**   The hierarchy of the type **EmployeeDaoImpl** is inconsistent